# How to reset class variables properly across instantiations

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

dict class variable is preserved across inheritance and instantiation:

```py
>>> class Superclass:
...   x = {'one': 1}
...   def __init__(self):
...     self.x['one'] += 1
... 
>>> class Subclass(Superclass):
...   def __init__(self):
...     super().__init__()
... 
>>> Subclass().x
{'one': 2}
>>> Subclass().x
{'one': 3}
>>> Subclass().x
{'one': 4}
>>> Subclass().x
{'one': 5}
>>> Subclass().x
{'one': 6}
>>> Subclass().x
{'one': 7}
```

How can I force `Superclass` to use a fresh dict every time it is instantiated, I would expect:

```py
>>> class Superclass:
...   x = {'one': 1}
...   def __init__(self):
...     self.x['one'] += 1
... 
>>> class Subclass(Superclass):
...   def __init__(self):
...     super().__init__()
... 
>>> Subclass().x
{'one': 2}
>>> Subclass().x
{'one': 2}
>>> Subclass().x
{'one': 2}
>>> Subclass().x
{'one': 2}
>>> Subclass().x
{'one': 2}
>>> Subclass().x
{'one': 2}
```

And also

```py
>>> class Superclass:
...   x = {'one': 1}
...   def __init__(self):
...     self.x['one'] += 1
... 
>>> class Subclass(Superclass):
...   x = {'one': 5}
...   def __init__(self):
...     super().__init__()
... 
>>> Subclass().x
{'one': 6}
>>> Subclass().x
{'one': 6}
>>> Subclass().x
{'one': 6}
>>> Subclass().x
{'one': 6}
>>> Subclass().x
{'one': 6}
>>> Subclass().x
{'one': 6}
```

Having an instance variable obviously doesn't work:

```py
>>> class Superclass:
...   def __init__(self):
...     self.x = {'one': 1}
...     self.x['one'] += 1
... 
>>> class Subclass(Superclass):
...   def __init__(self):
...     self.x = {'one': 5}
...     super().__init__()
... 
>>> Subclass().x # desired: {'one': 6}
{'one': 2}
>>> Subclass().x
{'one': 2}
>>> Subclass().x
{'one': 2}
>>> Subclass().x
{'one': 2}
>>> Subclass().x
{'one': 2}
>>> Subclass().x
{'one': 2}
```

A mixture doesn't work for when the superclass is reinstantiated:

```py
>>> class Superclass:
...   x = {'one': 1}
...   def __init__(self):
...     self.x['one'] += 1
... 
>>> class Subclass(Superclass):
...   def __init__(self):
...     self.x = {'one': 5}
...     super().__init__()
... 
>>> Superclass().x
{'one': 2}
>>> Superclass().x
{'one': 3}
>>> Superclass().x
{'one': 4}
>>> Superclass().x
{'one': 5}
>>> Superclass().x
{'one': 6}
>>> Superclass().x
{'one': 7}
```

What's a correct and established way to solve this problem?

Comment: Also, why do other data types like `int` work as expected out-the-box? Why is it only `dict`, `list` etc that have this problem?

Comment: Because dict and list are mutable objects, int is not

Comment: I think the instance variable method works, only correction that is needed is your call to the `__init__` of super class (i.e. super call) needs to precede your instance variable declaration. Class variable doesn't just seem right in my opinion

Comment: @sai but superclass init uses variables from subclass

Comment: @sai it would return `{'one': 5}` if I did as you suggest and not `{'one':6}` as I would like

Comment: True, but the subclass instance variables come first in the scope order. Of course it would be 5, the increment also needs to be done right. Correct me if I am wrong in understanding.

Comment: "but superclass init uses variables from subclass" - that is a recipe for nasty circular dependency issues. This is one of the reasons many languages *force* the superclass constructor call to be the first thing that happens in a subclass constructor.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica in those languages you can also override properties - actually, ig only in C# then. What's a better way to code it? I guess this alternative would fall under "a correct and established way to solve this problem"

Comment: @minseong: I don't know what languages you're thinking of, but in most examples I can think of, you can't (e.g. Java), or you can only do so to the extent you could in Python.

Comment: C# doesn't allow overriding fields, which would be the closest thing to what you've tried to write. It allows overriding properties, but Python allows that too.

Answer (score 3):

Make a copy of the dictionary in the `__init__` method.

```
class SuperClass():
    x = {'one': 1}

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = self.x.copy()
        self.x['one'] += 1

class SubClass(SuperClass):
    x = {'one': 5}

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

Answer (score 3):

You want subclasses to be able to override the code the superclass uses to construct its initial value of `x`, before it performs further modification. That's kind of a weird thing to override, but I would approach it by moving the construction of the initial `x` value into its own overridable method:

```
class Super:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = self._initial_x()
        self.x['one'] += 1
    @classmethod
    def _initial_x(cls):
        return {'one': 1}

class Sub(Super):
    @classmethod
    def _initial_x(cls):
        return {'one': 5}
```

Comment: Why make it a classmethod?

Comment: @minseong: Conceptual purity, mostly - a classmethod can't depend on uninitialized instance state.

Comment: Can a staticmethod "depend on unitialized instance state"?

Comment: @minseong: No, that was the reason I picked a classmethod over an instance method, rather than why I picked a classmethod over a staticmethod. For classmethod vs staticmethod, overriding a classmethod just feels more natural than overriding a staticmethod to me.